# Cannot delete paint brush nor texture in texture slots

Tags: osx

I accidentally duplicated the default paint brush multiple times while exploring the tool panel, and now I cannot get rid of them. I'm using MAC, latest version of Blender, I tried shift+ X +left click/right click, or control + X + left click/right click, but it doesn't work. I searched for shortcuts in preference key map and no keys are connected to such actions, and I cannot find the place in the tool panel to delete it without shortcut. Also I cannot find my brush folder( or any other presets folder) in file finder, help, the situation is desperate...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, <kbd>Shift</kbd> click on the X button:

[image]

Then, in the Outliner, select *Display Mode > Orphan Data*, press the *Purge* button or select the brush with a 0 and right click > *Delete*.

[image]

There might be another way but I don't know it...

Comment: thank you so much!! I finally deleted them, would not have achieved that in a hundred years without your help, but i still dont know where to delete the unwanted texture slots, is it also hidden somewhere?

Comment: same way, but you probably need to purge the materials first, then you'll be able to see the orphan images

Comment: also found where to delete the textures!! it is under display mode> blender file